# Equivalents to California's Ellis Act

Tags: united-states, rental-property, comparative-law, fair-housing-acts

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellis_Act),

> The Ellis Act (California Government Code Chapter 12.75)[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellis_Act) is a 1985 California state law that allows landlords to evict residential tenants to "go out of the rental business" in spite of desires by local governments to compel them to continue providing housing.

Are there any other US states that have equivalent legislation to the Ellis Act? I could not find any states with legislation equivalent to the Ellis Act in my research, however, I am skeptical of my search as I am not aware of what I may have missed due to alternate wordings.

Comment: Note that such a law only makes sense in a state that has rent control, which according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rent_control_in_the_United_States) is only CA, DC, MD, NJ, NY.  In the other 46 states, there'd be no need for such a law, because the landlord already has the right to simply decline to renew the lease.

Comment: That makes my search easier. Thanks! @NateEldredge

Comment: Also worth noting that rent control in some of the states that have it is imposed at the local government level, rather than at the state level, so the relevant law would be contained in local ordinances rather than state statutes. Furthermore, it is likely that in some jurisdiction the same rule may exist by virtue of case law rather than a statute or ordinance.